# Rebus - Deferred Message, exactly one message handler

Tags: rebus

I was wondering if the Rebus Service Bus can handle the following use cases:

- Queue messages for a future date
- if there is a message ProcessInvoice with a context like Customer Id: 1000, can we have exactly one handler executing the message. So in case the message is duplicated, it does not get processed again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure - Rebus can `bus.Defer` a message some `TimeSpan` into the future - e.g. to postpone the delivery of a message to some specific date, something like this could do it:

```
var delay = utcTimeOfWhenToDeliverTheMessage - DateTime.UtcNow;

bus.Defer(delay, messageToPostpone);
```

which requires that a timeout manager has been configured. You can configure a timeout manager by going

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Timeouts(t => t.(...))
```

in the Rebus configuration spell.

If you want to guarantee that a given message is processed only once even though duplicates might be delivered, there's a couple of things to consider - it's hard to tell you the easiest way to handle it, because sometimes it can be easy to simply make the performed action [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), other times you'd need to track the ID of the processed message etc.